# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'botorch.utils.multi_objective'

Tags: python, pytorch, modulenotfounderror

Although I have installed `botorch`, when I want to run `from botorch.utils.multi_objective.box_decompositions.non_dominated import NondominatedPartitioning`, it shows the following error:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'botorch.utils.multi_objective'`

Does anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: How did you install botorch?

Comment: @DerekO I installed it by writing the command ```sudo pip3 install botorch```